# Unable to locate element using text when <!--> is available inside the label

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Have the HTML code as below.and i want to locate the element using the text SOFTWATE.

```
<label _ngcontent-c5="" class="form-check-label" style="" xpath="1">
  <input _ngcontent-c5="" class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox">
  <!----> 
  <!---->
  <span _ngcontent-c5="" class="checkmark">
  </span>
  SOFTWARE 
</label>
```

Tried with the xpath `//div[@class='filter-item-wrapper activate']//label[contains(text(),'SOFTWARE')]`, but no luck.

Anyone could please help to find the locate the element using the text '`SOFTWARE`'

Answer (score 1):

try with the following it may work.

```
//div[@class='filter-item-wrapper activate']//label[contains(.,'SOFTWARE')]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you please explain what is the use of  '.' in [contains(.,'SOFTWARE')] and also the meaning of normalize-space(.) in xpath

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely why we always advise people to avoid using `text()` to access text nodes directly. It's nearly always better to use `string()` to access the string value of the containing element, and one of the big differences is that the result of `string()` is unaffected by adding or removing comments.

So use `contains(string(), 'SOFTWARE')` -- which can then be abbreviated to `contains(., 'SOFTWARE')`, because a call on `string()` is implicit when a string is required and you supply a node.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you simply don't want to *locate the element* but you want to `click()` on the *checkbox* as well and to achieve that you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.form-check-label>input.form-check-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid[type='checkbox']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='form-check-label' and normalize-space()='SOFTWARE']/input[@class='form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
//div/descendant-or-self::label[normalize-space(.)='SOFTWARE']
```

This should strip out any additional leading or trailing whitespace before trying to match the text.